# Getting property of non-object when looping through post objects from ACF

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a site using Root's Sage Wordpress theme which uses the blade templating engine.

I have a repeater field in ACF with many post objects. When I foreach loop through the repeater to retrieve the post objects, I am getting a `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` errors. When I turn off WP_Debug, these errors are not present and the following code works as expected.

Below is a snippet of the code used:

```
global $post; 

@foreach($page_column as $pages)


    {{-- If the link is internal --}}
    @if($pages['link_type'] === "Internal")

        @foreach($pages as $post)

            @php 

            setup_postdata($post); 

            @endphp

            <li class="footer__list-item">

                <a class="footer__link" href="{{get_the_permalink($post->ID)}}">{{$post->post_title}}</a>

            </li>

            @php wp_reset_postdata(); @endphp

        @endforeach

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Below is what is output:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44
Home

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44
About

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44
Locations

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44
Case Studies

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44
Downloads

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /homepages/6/d142103519/htdocs/development-sites/newable-3.0/wp-content/uploads/cache/0df15fedcc33b7f94d22294aa741cea17fe36f28.php on line 44
```

What is interesting is you can see the code is working as intended because below most of the error messages, you can see the post title being output. I also do not understand why there are multiple errors thrown per page as the code is retrieving all the pages from the repeater field successfully.

From what I found when looking up the error, I added in the `setup_postdata($post)` to see if that would fix the issue however that does not seem to have worked.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I would turn off the debug!

Comment: @Elkrat I like to have it on whilst developing.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, after a couple of minutes, I figured out the issue.

Instead of passing the `$post->ID` into `get_the_permalink`, I can just not pass any parameters in as the `setup_postdata($post)` takes care of this.